# How to change JLabel text and JButton position at the same time

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I just want to move a button when clicked on it and also I want to change the label text.

I wrote code for moving the button and it's working fine for me.  But when I want to change the label text to different name it's not happening.

Either the button is moving from its place or the labels text is changed. But I want to perform both actions at once i.e. on button click event. I tried so many things as I could. Can some body help me?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaGUI extends JPanel {

    private Control control = new Control();
    private Keys keys = new Keys("Original starting value.");

    public JavaGUI() {        
        this.add(keys);
        this.add(control);
    }

    private class Control extends JPanel {

        public Control() {
            this.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Update") {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Command: " + e.getActionCommand());
                    keys.string = String.valueOf(System.nanoTime());
                    //keys.label.setText(keys.string);          
                    // If I remove these comments button will not move. bt I want both...
                    JButton j = (JButton) e.getSource();
            j.setLocation(j.getX()+10,j.getY()+10);
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    private class Keys extends JPanel {

        private String string;
        private JLabel label = new JLabel();

        public Keys(String s) {
            this.string = s;
            label.setText(s);
            this.add(label);
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JavaGUI");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JavaGUI().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any reason to extend the 3 panels.  Just keep instances.

Comment: all code is worrking fine dear. How to change label text with moving button.

Comment: *"all code is worrking fine dear"*  Not according to your question pet.

Comment: i cant understand what u mean. can u explain it ?

Comment: I can't bare to read mumbling text-speak.  Can you use your shift key at the start of sentences and spell words properly?

Comment: Ok ok dude. Do you have answer of my question.

Comment: *"Can some body help me?"*  Unknown at this stage.  Few others would attempt to create such an odd GUI.  I don't actually have the motivation to try and help you achieve this (what is it anyway - yet another fatally broken GUI builder?) & that is why *I made a comment on the one aspect of the code that jumped out at me as being bad design.*

Comment: Actually I am devloping a 3*3 puzzle game. I want to add clock in d game. But when adding clock the blocks are not moving. So do you want me to show d code. If you say I post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move a button just like that, the layout manager tells it where it should be. Calling setText triggers the effect of layout manager for the whole component hierarchy. If you really want to do this, you should set a null layout manager, and manage all the sizes and locations of all components manually.

Even if your button was moving in your original code, it was not painted correctly as soon as it left its original place - you could accidentally abuse Swing, but not completely.

Working solution:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MovingButton {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                buildFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void buildFrame() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        p.setLayout(null);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Starting Text on Label");
        label.setLocation(200, 0);
        label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
        p.add(label);

        final JButton b = new JButton("Button");
        b.setSize(b.getPreferredSize());
        b.setLocation(0, 0);
        p.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                b.setLocation((int)b.getLocation().getX() + 20, (int)b.getLocation().getY() + 20);
                label.setText(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()));
            }
        });


        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean that I edited my answer to include full working code where a button moves and a label is updated...

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the class that holds the JLabel a public method that accepts a String and that is called when other objects wish to change the text held by the label, something like:

```
public void setLabelText(String text) {
   label.setText(text);
}
```

Then any object with a reference to the JLabel displaying object can easily change the label's text.

Regarding your moving button, you'll want to read up on layout managers. JPanels use FlowLayout by default, and this does not accept setBounds(...) or setLocation(...) of components.

Comment: I tried this code, and interestingly, the button does move if the label text is not updated. Why would that be?

Comment: @ShyamalPandya: It may move but it won't be a stable move if you leave the layout as FlowLayout. Resize your GUI and your button will "unmove". You will want to learn about layout managers and the tutorials will help you in this.

Comment: I dont think its d right way. why calling setLabelText method instead of setText.   And I also change the layout. Yet its not working friend.

Comment: I cant get your words. can you explain it more.